# не отправляются данные в mockapi

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, api, бот

Не отправляются данные в mockapi через телеграм выводится Введите имя и при отправке сообщения ничего не происходит

```
const axios = require('axios');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const telegramToken = 'токен';
const bot = new TelegramBot(telegramToken, { polling: true });

// Функция для отправки сообщения в Telegram
async function sendMessage(chatId, message) {
    try {
        const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${telegramToken}/sendMessage`;
        const data = {
            chat_id: chatId,
            text: message,
        };

        await axios.post(url, data);
        console.log('Сообщение успешно отправлено в Telegram');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при отправке сообщения в Telegram:', error);
    }
}

// Ваш код для получения данных
fetch('https://652e50390b8d8ddac0b12649.mockapi.io/person/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
})
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error('Error: ' + res.status);
        }
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

        const message = JSON.stringify(data);
        sendMessage(chatId, message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

// Обработчик команды /addrecord
bot.onText(/\/addrecord/, (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    // Отправляем сообщение с просьбой ввести данные
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Введите имя:');
   
    // Ожидаем ответ от пользователя
    bot.onReplyToMessage(chatId, msg.message_id, async (reply) => {
        const nameos = reply.text;

        try {
            // Отправляем запрос на добавление данных в MockAPI
            const mockApiUrl = 'https://652e50390b8d8ddac0b12649.mockapi.io/person/';
            const response = await axios.post(mockApiUrl, {
                createdAt: '2023-10-18',
                name: nameos,
                avatar: 'img.jpg',
                years: 40,
                id: '9'
            });

            // Проверяем статус ответа
            if (response.status === 201) {
                bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Данные успешно добавлены в MockAPI!');
            } else {
                bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ошибка при добавлении данных в MockAPI.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.');
        }
    });
});
```